# var_dump() imprimindo o número zero em vez de imprimir o elemento da posição

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer uma saída de dados simples na tela, criei um array:

```
$arr1617 = [02,05,06,07,08,09,10,12,13,14,15,20,22,23,25];
```

Após isso usei a função `var_dump()` para gerar um saída de dados, porém o output sai com um erro de impressão:

```
array (size=15) 
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 6
  3 => int 7 
  **4 => int 0 <--**
  **5 => int 0 <--**
  6 => int 10
  7 => int 12
  8 => int 13
  9 => int 14
  10 => int 15
  11 => int 20
  12 => int 22
  13 => int 23
  14 => int 25
```

Eu sei que retirando o número zero a esquerda resolveria o problema, mas fiquei curioso em saber o porquê isso ocorre.

Comment: Numeros com 0 à esquerda são numeros em octal.

Comment: Então, o ruim é que tenho um txt com números assim, aí irei ter que transformar em string, remover os zeros a esquerda, voltar para inteiro e depois colocar no banco.

Comment: Basta transformar em `string` e utilizar [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php) especificando ou não base 10 pois é a base por defeito

Comment: Irei tentar essa solução, obrigado.